# Edit rejected by OP for spurious reason, missing an important change - how do I educate him/her?

Tags: discussion

The question contained an external link to an image. I changed it to an inline image and explained the change in the title. I made a few changes to the text to get to the 6-char limit (and the changes were good but not particularly significant). The OP rejected the edit, complaining that it did not make the question any clearer (he actually thought that it made it worse, despite the fact that he himself later edited the question and incorporated most of them :-)) but he missed the important part: the inlining of the image. The question was edited later and somebody else inlined the image again, but I wonder if there was a missed opportunity to educate the OP. Is there a protocol to explain to a user what he missed in an edit?

Comment: It's quite possible that the asker didn't understand what you were trying to do, since the only apparent changes in the source are an exclamation point, a space, and an unnecessary rewording that's only there to hit the limit. You can always leave a comment explaining to the OP what you were doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought about doing that and decided against it. The trouble is that there are a dozen comments there that are relevant to the question, so I was worried that a comment about a rejected edit that nobody except the OP knows about, would look irrelevant and be confusing to just about everybody.

Comment: More generally, when you edit the post of a new user, it might be reasonable to leave a short comment explaining what you have done.  It may help them to learn how to write better questions...

Comment: I agree: that's what I should have done. I'll try to remember next time.

Comment: Perhaps next time introduce suitable [alternate text](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11081/36526) in addition to inlining the image.  That way, the image will be accessible to visually impaired users, and you won't have to make superfluous edits to hit the limit.

Comment: Thanks! That is a very good suggestion.